# ¿Cómo evitar que un usuario ingrese a un post que se encuentra aun en borrador? (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, middleware

En la tabla que almaceno los registros de los post, he agregado un campo llamado status. Este campo lo utilizo para listar solo los post cuyo status sea 2, que son los post publicados (los que tienes status 1 significa que aún están en borrador)

Mi problema radica en que si el usuario conociera la url de algún post que no está publicado, podría ingresar. Por lo que en el método show llamo a la vista de la siguiente manera.

```
public function show(Post $post)
{
   
    if($post->status == 1){
        abort(403, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }else{
       
        return view('blog.show', compact('post'));
    }
}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente ¿Cómo podría hacer lo mismo pero con un middleware? he estado leyendo en la documentación, y en varios post, y siempre ponen ejemplos de como evitar que un usuario ingrese, si es que no tiene un determinado rol ¿Cómo podría hacer lo mismo, pero indicandole al middleware que no le permita el ingreso si es que el post al que quiere acceder tiene status 1?

Comment: Eso he hecho. Y como digo ese no es el problema, el problema es que si el usuario conoce la url va poder ingresar.

Imaginemos que un post que ya he publicado, decido pasarlo a borrador. Si un usuario ha guardado esa url, va poder ingresar al post, y eso es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Imaginemos que he publicado un post, y un usuario lo guarda en los accesos rapidos de chrome. Pasado un tiempo, decido que ese post ya no quiero que sea visible, pero no quiero eliminarlo, así que lo paso a borrador.

Un usuario nuevo no va a poder acceder a ese post ya que no le aparecerá en la vista index, pero un usuario que guardo el link si va poder acceder al post.

En si ya he logrado evitar el accedo poniendo un abort en el metodo show, en el caso de que el status del post sea 1, pero lo que quiero saber es si puedo delegar ese trabajo a un middleware

Answer (score 0):

Considero que con una consulta de este estilo debe alcanzar:

```
Post::whereStatus(2)->get();
```

Me explico:

- Cuando construyes la consulta te estará devolviendo una colección con los registros que satisfagan las condiciones dadas
- En tu  vista solo vas a ser capaz de mostrar los valores de las propiedades de los registros que obtuviste en la consulta
- Aunque el usuario conozca por ejemplo el id de un post previo que de activo pasaste a borrador si este no esta dentro de la colección no va a poder ser accesible a el y estaría retornando un error 404 (por que dime si no existe en la colección ¿de donde lo va a obtener?), recuerda que el usuario consume lo que el backend desde una sentencia SQL (para este caso) le retorne
- En este caso considero es mas simple valerte de una sentencia SQL que precisamente ayuda a *hablarle* a la base de datos para pedirle solo aquellos datos que necesitemos
- No es que un middleware no sirva para una acción como esta pero ¿para qué? si con filtrar los datos en la consulta debe alcanzar

Comment: Con eso logro que no se liste los post en la vista index, pero no es lo que quiero solucionar.

Imaginemos que tengo un post que se pueda acceder con este link mi-sitio-web/blog/articulo1. El usuario le gusta este articulo y lo guarda en la barra de accedo rapido de chrome.

Pasado un tiempo quiero que ese post no sea visible, pero no quiero eliminarlo, por lo que lo paso a borrador. Ese post ya no aparecerá en la vista index, pero si hay un usuario que guardo el link si podría acceder a ese post, y es lo que quiero evitar.

Comment: Pero volvemos a lo mismo los datos los toma de lo que la consulta te devolvió, si ese que se guardo como favorito lo pasamos a borrador entonces ya no cumple la condición y no será parte de los resultados de la consulta, no es posible que si lo vea

Comment: Creo que ya ten entendí. Yo estaba rescatando el registro de esta manera public function show(Post $post), por lo que ya no tenía que hacer ninguna otra consulta.

Voy a rescatarlo poniendole el filtro adicional del status. Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Claro y vienes a comentarnos si quedó o no, para que si no funciona elimino esto

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es implementar autorización.
Especificamente, revisa la sección de [policy-methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#policy-methods).

Mira el ejemplo:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Post;
use App\User;

class PostPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine if the given post can be updated by the user.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Post  $post
     * @return bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Post $post)
    {
        return $user->id === $post->user_id;
    }
}
```

Con esta política del ejemplo, solo el usuario dueño del post puede actualizar el post.

Tu puedes añadir una política tal que solo se actualize cuando el post tenga status 1:

```
public function update(Post $post)
    {
        return $post->status == 1;
    }
```

El comando para crear políticas sobre modelos es:

```
php artisan make:policy {Modelo}Policy --model={Modelo}
```

Comment: Si he intentado hacerlo con un policy, pero me da un error cuando el usuario no está autentificado, por más que en el policy no este pidiendo en ningún momento información del usuario autentificado.

Comment: Puedes usar el [type-hint](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authorization#guest-users) ```?User $user ... optional($user)```, para evitar lo de la autenticación.

Comment: La autorización valida por defecto que el usuario esté autenticado, puedes usar el type-hint "optional" o proveer un valor null por defecto para el usuario en el argumento para evitar ese check.